# No obtengo el resultado deseado en Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap

Estoy empezando con Bootstrap creando una cabecera de una pagina, basándome en la pagina de este enlace https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar/ y un tutorial de JavaDevOne en yt. Mi problema es que el resultado que obtengo no es el que va acorde ni con el ejemplo de bootstrap ni con el del tutorial.

Adjunto mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!-- Etiqueta que sirve para IE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- Hara que la web tenga un tamaño normal independientemente del dispositivo -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- Cargamos el css de bootstrap.min.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css"> <!-- Cargamos el css de estilos.css -->

    <title>Pagina</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- Cargamos el js de jquery -->
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script> <!-- Cargamos el js de popper -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- Cargamos el js de bootstrap -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toogle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Este boton cambia la barra de navegacion</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DAW208</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>Inicio</li>
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi situación:
[image: MiEstado]

Lo esperado:
[image: Lo deseado]

Comment: Haz los ejercicios de clase solo, asi aprenderas. Que ya estas en segundo de daw :P

Comment: Probé solamente el código de tu cabecera en una plantilla de [Codepen](https://codepen.io/CrisMVP3200/pen/pWPOYo). La cabecera está bien. Al parecer el problema está en como estás referenciando los archivos requeridos para Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo un ejemplo de como debería de quedar tu estructura de la pagina.

Si funciona, el problema esta en que no estas llegando a las librerias, debes checar que las librerias esten al mismo nivel que tu index

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!-- Etiqueta que sirve para IE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- Hara que la web tenga un tamaño normal independientemente del dispositivo -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- Cargamos el css de bootstrap.min.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css"> <!-- Cargamos el css de estilos.css -->

    <title>Pagina</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- Cargamos el js de jquery -->
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script> <!-- Cargamos el js de popper -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- Cargamos el js de bootstrap -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toogle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Este boton cambia la barra de navegacion</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DAW208</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tengo el index y dos carpetas a su nivel (css y js) y referencio todo justo debajo del body. Pero ni obteniendo el enlace desde la web como haces tu en  el ejemplo puedo lograr el resultado deseado

Comment: Ya lo probe en mi maquina, y funciona bien, checa si en la carpeta css el nombre de  bootstrap.min.css esta escrito asi, o asi: bootstrap.css

Comment: Tengo el min y en el html referencio el min. Acabo de probar con el normal y sigo en las mismas.

Comment: Algo debe de captar ya que la caja me la pinta en pantalla y la fuente no es la misma a la de html por defewcto

Comment: puedes subir captura de tu directorio?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/hBq1D

Comment: la imagen 2 esta dentro de la carpeta css

Comment: Y el nombre de la carpeta que contiene todo eso como se llama?

Comment: Se llama css. En el html lo referencio de esta manera <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- Cargamos el css de bootstrap.min.css -->

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66347/discussion-between-luis-fernando-and-eduardo-mendez).